# MVC Autocomplete Textbox using JSON returns NULL on Post

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I want my search box to autocomplete values from the database. It is correctly hitting the controller as I type something in the search box, but the string value is returning NULL no matter what I try. Here's my code:

View (partial view):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchBar", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="searcharea">
            @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { placeholder = "Type search here..." } )
            <input type="submit" />
        </div>
    </div>

}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#SearchString").autocomplete({
            source: "/Home/AutoCompleteSearch",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
                    $("#SearchString").val(ui.item.value);
                    $("form").submit();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteSearch(string SearchString)
{
    var values = from s in db.Customers
                              select s.CustomerNumber;

    var namelist = values.Where(n => n.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchString));
    return Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

So as I type in the search box, I come to this controller, but the string SearchString, is NULL. I was following this [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b19d5a/autocomplete-textbox-using-database-return-value-in-Asp-Net/).

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but do you have any data in the 'customers` table in your DB?

Comment: could be a case sensitivity issue, try: var namelist = values.Where(n => n.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchString.ToLower()));
if it did not work, debug c# check if you have actually entries in the namelist var, then if it still does not work debug js on the client side.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the customers table or even the var namelist. The problem is before that. it's the parameter string SearchString. That value is null when I come to the controller. @AmmarHamidou it's not carrying the search box value back to the controller from the view

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteSearch(string SearchString)
{
    var values = from s in db.Customers
                              select s.CustomerNumber;

    var namelist = values.Where(n => n.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchString.ToLower()));
    return Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```